# How to get a Window in visual studio having all prototypes of a class

Tags: c++

I am making a CString class having a lot of functions in it.I have made it but when I call any func and navigate up and down to see it's def it's so time cosuming. Please tell me How can I get a Window having all prototypes of a function in a class ,so that I click and it would show me its def

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class view window. To open it, go to the view menu and then select Class View. In the class view window you can select the class you are interested in. You can then see al its members and methods, wich you can double click to immediately go the definition.